# AppSync client query not returning complete data response

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, dynamodb-queries

I am having an issue getting results back from my AppSync API via AWSAppSyncClient. I can run the query in the AWS AppSync console and get the complete results, however when I run the query from my client the portion of the results I am looking for returns an empty array.

I have tried slimming down the query to return less results, as I read at one point that dynamo will run a filter on the results being returned if you do not provide your own. I have also read this could have something to do with the partition keys used in the dynamoDB table, however AppSync provisioned that resource for me and handled the initial config. I am new to working with AppSync so I am sort of drawing a blank on where to even start looking for the issue because there is not even an error message.

The Query I am running

```
export const getUserConversations = `query getUser($id: ID!) {
  getUser(id: $id) {
    id
    conversations {
      items {
        conversation{
          id
          associated{
            items{
              convoLinkUserId
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`;
```

Call being made in a redux actions file

```
export const getUserConvos = (id) => async dispatch => {

  AppSyncClient.query({
    query: gql(getUserConversations),
    variables: {
      id: id
    }
  }).then(res => {
    console.log("RES FROM CONVO QUERY", res)
  })

}
```

This is the response I am getting in the browser
Notice conversations.items returns an empty array.

```
getUser:
conversations:
items: []
__typename: "ModelConvoLinkConnection"
__proto__: Object
id: "HIDDEN_ID"
__typename: "User"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

However if i run the exact same query in the playground on the AppSync console I get this...

```
{
  "data": {
    "getUser": {
      "id": "HIDDEN_ID",
      "conversations": {
        "items": [
          {
            "conversation": {
              "id": "HIDDEN_ID",
              "associated": {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "convoLinkUserId": "HIDDEN_ID"
                  },
                  {
                    "convoLinkUserId": "HIDDEN_ID"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "conversation": {
              "id": "HIDDEN_ID",
              "associated": {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "convoLinkUserId": "HIDDEN_ID"
                  },
                  {
                    "convoLinkUserId": "HIDDEN_ID"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*HIDDEN_ID is a placeholder

I know that the objects are in my DB, however if i run the query via my react application I get nothing, and if I run it in the console on AWS I get another. I need to be able to have access to these conversations via the client. What could be causing this?

Comment: Could you please share you `schema.graphql` file?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you ever find a solution?